# Offline note taking app that preserves HTML formatting

Tags: linux, offline, note-taking

I am currently using **Evernote**. I am on Ubuntu and there is no desktop client for Ubuntu. The web version is limited. I'm looking for an Evernote alternative that can preserve web page formatting and works offline.

If I copy some content like images and text and paste it into the note, it should look the same.
Also I don't want cloud syncing. It should store data locally.

The closest I came by is **OpenNote**, but I have issues with connecting it with CouchDB. Also the last commit was 2 years ago, so I doubt if it's still maintained.

Caveats:

When you clip a web content with images, I think Evernote converts the image to base64 encoded data and saves it along with the text. I exported the note into enex and tested. It does not just save the link to the image. I tried tagspaces. It is able to preserve formatting of copied contents when the note is HTML, but it links the images. So if the images go offline, then the page will be broken, which makes it not really offline.

Tried MHTML, but it saves images in tmp folder. Not very useful.

I found MAFF to work well offline. I saves the page completely offline in an archive which Firefox can read. I use Recoll for indexing and search, but not sure if it will work with this.

Update: Saving as single web page using MHTML flag enabled in Chrome saves everything locally.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started using QOwnNotes (http://www.qownnotes.org/) for similar reasons. It's free and open source. Does not work directly with HTML, but instead it uses Markdown, which renders to HTML. Hope it fits your needs.

Comment: Since it's using markdown, it won't work for web clippings. If I copy a web page and paste it, all formatting, styles, positioning will not be maintained.

Comment: @kadaj have you tried? Usually Markdown allows for "embedding HTML snippets". In fact, as Markdown just supports a subset of HTML features, that's how it's often used.

Comment: lzzy: it does not work as intended. I am looking for clipping feature, means in evernote, you can simple copy a web page portion, drag into the note editior, and it preserves the style. Since markup is completely text based, I cannot simply drag and drop. It does not preserve the style of copied content. For creating content, markdown is okay. OpenNote editor used to work like this under Windows, but in Ubuntu it is not working.